# How to create a Power BI DataSet Scheduled Refresh programatically

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-api

**Requirement**: To create a Power BI Dataset scheduled refresh through code and use it in DevOps process, so that I do not have to create scheduled refresh explicitly from Power BI web portal.

**What I tried/research**: I could not find Power BI API explicitly to create scheduled refresh. So, I tried to use update refresh schedule datasets API: [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshSchedule](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7BdatasetId%7D/refreshSchedule)
Refer: [MicrosoftDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updaterefreshschedule)

**Observed**: If the schedule is OFF - this API turns ON the schedule and updates the refresh schedule of the dataset. However, to achieve this I had to create schedule at least once using the Power BI web portal. Then if I turn off the schedule and run the above API, it turns ON the schedule and updates refresh schedule timings.

Are any workarounds to setup a Power BI Dataset scheduled refresh via API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is by using the 'Update refresh schedule in group' endpoint:

[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshSchedule](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/datasets/%7BdatasetId%7D/refreshSchedule)

Refer: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updaterefreshscheduleingroup)

In the body you can specify your schedule. I use this in a python script to set my schedules automatically. As body I use:

```
 {"value": 
    {"days":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],
     "times": ["05:00"],
     "enabled": 'true',
     "localTimeZoneId": "UTC"
  }}
```

Comment: thanks. I missed to explicitly add "enabled" : true.